# Query regarding Database operations with spinner

Tags: android, android-ndk

**I have saved some data from spinner in to the database. But I am stuck while retrieving data. I need to retrieve the spinner value to text box so please help me.  **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text1.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

or

```
text1.setText(getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
```